Cross currency Swap Pricing under T- forward measure
Let's assume we are in a frictionless market where the covered interest rate parity exactly holds i.e.
\begin{align}
F^X(0,T) &=X_0 \frac{P^f(0,T)}{P^d(0,T)}
\end{align}
where $X_0$ is the FX spot, $P^f(0,T)$ and $P^d(0,T)$ the present value of a foreign and a domestic ZCB.
Let's assume we want to price a single coupon libor payment $L_f(S,T)$ at  $T$ of the foreign leg of a XCCY swap reported in Domestic currency.
One way to do it is:
\begin{align*}
PV_d = X_0 P^f(0,T)E_f^T( L_f(S,T)\mid \mathcal{F}_t) &= X_0 P^f(0,T)F_f(0,S,T)
\end{align*}
i.e we do all the calculation under the foreign $T$ - forward measure and at $t=0$ we convert everything to domestic currency using the FX spot $X_0$
This also implies(using the definition of the fx forward):
\begin{align*}
PV_d = F^X(0,T)P^d(0,T)F_f(0,S,T) \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Does (1) hold?
The other way to compute the PV is basically convert to domestic currency at T and now under domestic T-forward measure we have:
\begin{align*}
PV_d = P^d(0,T)E_d^T(X_TL_f(S,T)\mid \mathcal{F}_t) 
\end{align*}
In order to reach (1) can we simply split the product inside the expectation?
i.e $E_d^T(X_T\mid \mathcal{F}_t)E_d^T(L_f(S,T)\mid \mathcal{F}_t)$


First of all: unless your $t$ is zero something seems wrong because
using $P^d(0,T),P^f(0,T)$ you are discounting back to zero.
Therefore I shall use $t=0$ from now on.

Regarding your question if (1) holds: did you not just prove it?

Now to the question at the bottom of OP:

Even if you could split the product inside the expectation
$$\tag1
PV_d = P^d(0,T)\,\mathbb E_d^T\big[X_T\,L_f(S,T)\big]
$$
you would get
\begin{align}\tag2
PV_d &= P^d(0,T)\,\underbrace{\mathbb E_d^T\big[X_T\big]}_{F^X(0,T)}\,\mathbb E_d^T\big[L_f(S,T)\big]\\[2mm]
&=X_0P^f(0,T)\,\mathbb E_{\color{red}d}^T\big[L_f(S,T)\big]\tag3
\end{align}
which has a wrong currency in that expectation.

The solution to the riddle is that the relationship
$$\tag4
X_t\,P^f(t,T)\,\mathbb E_f^T[H\mid{\cal F}_t]=P^d(t,T)\,\mathbb E_d^T[X_T\,H\mid{\cal F}_t]
$$
says nothing else that the PV of a foreign payoff $H$ must be the same regardless

if it is calculated in the foreign measure and converted to $d\,,$ or

if it is converted at $T$ to $d$ and calculated in the domestic measure.

From (4) you could again deduce your equation (1).


